# What cable provides support for dual external monitors at 1920x1080 on a MacBook Air?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, video-adapter

I'm considering getting a new MacBook Air computer and would like it to drive two external monitors at 1920x1080 resolution.

What cable or adapter would I need to run such a configuration?

A related [question for MacBook Pros](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33809/dual-monitor-output-from-a-new-macbook-pro) mentions some solutions that might apply here:

- Would Two Apple Thunderbolt Displays work?
- Would a DisplayLink adapter work with standard 1080p displays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My information is second-hand, but another user at my company gave an strongly enthusiastic recommendation of a "NewerTech" USB to DVI adapter. Note that this will require use of their driver, but he has had no issues with it. It is available from [OWC](http://eshop.macsales.com/item/NewerTech/VIDU2DVIA/).

Comment: I'm doubtful that USB would be able to accomplish this without downgrading the resolution or refresh time.

Comment: Here is his pruned recommendation: "I'm running the  adapter on my 2010-vintage MBP7,1 running 10.7.5, driving an  1920x1080 LG screen via DVI.
Simultaneously, I'm driving a 2560x1440 DELL U2711 via a mini-DispayAdapter to DisplayAdapter cable.
 
It works *surprisingly* well from this 2.66 Intel Core2 Duo...
It's not perfectly responsive as the MBP's Display Adapter output when you tell it to display a full-screen movie with lots of action,
and in extreme cases (I tried with lots of video windows) it can bog down.
For normal dektop use, maybe with an occasional video window, it's flawless.
"